# Installing Eclipse with C++ for scientific linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I installed Eclipse on this scientific linux machine a while back. But when I  go to Windows -> Preferences, I do not see C++ listed. I then went to Help -> Install New SOftware -> WOrk with -> Eclipse Juno repository and only checked "C/C++ Development Tools". I then got the message "operation cannot be completed" and under details it says

`Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: C/C++ Development Tools 8.1.2.201302132326 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 8.1.2.201302132326)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1306272994665 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1306272994665)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Debug Core 3.7.100.v20120521-2012 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.100.v20120521-2012)
    Debug Core 3.6.0.v20100519 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.6.0.v20100519)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1306272994665 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1306272994665)
    To: org.eclipse.debug.core [3.6.0.v20100519]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Development Tools Debugger UI 7.2.0.201302132326 (org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui 7.2.0.201302132326)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.debug.core [3.7.0,4.0.0)"`

How can I resolve this? Is there another I can use C++ with Eclipse?

Comment: You don't need Eclipse to code in C++. A lot of very good C++ coders are using a mixture of better and simpler tools (`emacs`,`make`,`git`,`g++`,`gdb` ....)

Comment: I'm dealing with a huge codebase that none of my coworkers understand and small, seemingly innocuous changes causes crashes. I've been spending about a month debugging this and `gdb` isn't helping much. I already use `make` and `CMakeFiles`

Comment: If you really want to use an IDE, you may consider Qt Creator. In addition, you may find [this thread on Reddit](http://redd.it/2w0dh6) interesting.

Comment: As a case in point [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is a large code base in C++ (more than ten millions lines) and I know nobody working on it with Eclispe.

Comment: I'm having difficulty installing Qt creator too? Should I try something else like KDevelop?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the CDT plugin using your distribution repositories.

```
sudo yum install eclipse-cdt
```

Comment: Trying that I got the message `user is not allowed to execute usr/bin/yum install eclipse-cdt as root`

Comment: That message means you need additional privileges to execute yum.  Ask your administrator to execute that command for you or to add you as a sudoer.

Comment: Says "No package eclipse-cdt available." on SL7.1.